# Using ASP.NET MVC with entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In most of MVC tutorials, I have seen the usage of entity framework with MVC. Why is entity framework always used along with MVC? Is there any particular advantage for that combination?

Comment: Probably because Entity Framework is Microsoft's currently preferred data access technology ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Why is entity framework always used along with MVC?

I think primarily because:

- Ease of availability (installed with Visual Studio template)
- Easy integration into an existing project (Nuget packages are available to install).

> Any particular advantage for that combination?

Well it is subjective question but if you are a MS Developer you will find using EF involves:

- Less learning curve: Existing MS developers finds it easy to pick up a new technology originating from MS. The familiarity with .NET framework leads to less learning curve or easy troubleshooting.
- Support and documentation - As Microsoft developed it, they updated it regularly with several new feature added between version 3.5 to now EF 6.1.2 (as on 4/17/2015). As large number of people making use of this ORM, finding help is not difficult both from MS and community.